# QGIS 3.16 Python script: processAlgorithm return empty layer

Tags: qgis, python

The script process well except the returned output. I want that the script displays the `"output_layer"` at the end of my script as a temporary layer in my QGIS project.
I understand that the output have to be a sink type.

Following this tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_scripts.html, I try to add the features of the `output_layer` in sink at the end of the script.

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
     
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(self.INPUT_vector,self.tr( 
    'couche parcelle'), 
    types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon],
    defaultValue=None)
    )
    
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(self.INPUT_raster,self.tr(
    'raster classification'),
    defaultValue=None)
    )

    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(self.OUTPUT, self.tr('Output layer'), type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
    

    
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):       
    
    source = self.parameterAsSource(
        parameters,
        self.INPUT_vector,
        context
    )        


    (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
        parameters,
        self.OUTPUT,
        context,
        source.fields(),
        source.wkbType(),
        source.sourceCrs()
    )
    

    [...]
    

    # At the end of the script: Read output_layer and create output sink

    for f in output_layer['OUTPUT'].getFeatures():
        sink.addFeature(f, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
        feedback.pushInfo('feature: {}'.format(f.fields().names()))
    
    
    return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

The displayed output layer contains the input layer fields instead of the `output_layer` fields. `feedback.pushInfo` displays correct info, `"output_layer"` is OK.

What is the correct code to have `"output_layer"` correctly returned and displayed at the end of the script?

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer using "Answer Your Question" button beneath the thread. Let the question body contain only the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly find the solution:

The problem comes from the sink construction. line:

```
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(...)
```

I changed the `source.fields()` to `output_layer['OUTPUT'].fields()`

`source.fields()` was limiting the number of fields with the number of fields of the input layer.

Answer (score 5):

First, you **have to** add the following method to your processing algorithm class to be able to add  temporary layers to the project.

```
def flags(self):
    return super().flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
```

Then use this anywhere before `return`:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer['OUTPUT'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it works without def flags.